# How to make a button do one thing half the time and another the other half

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button that a user presses when they select something which sends them to another page. I want there to be a 50/50 chance whether this sends them to one page or another. Right now I am doing this with `Math.random()`:

```
onButtonClick = () => {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    this.props.history.push({pathname: "/foo"})
  } else {
    this.props.history.push({pathname: "/bar"})
  }
}
```

However this has the possibility to randomly send the user to the same page more than the other. I was thinking of implementing some counter than sends the user to one page if the counter is odd and to the other if it was even, but I am unsure as to how to do this. Any suggestions?

Comment: With a counter it would alternately redirect to each page in turn, is that what you want?

Comment: What makes you think "that this has the possibility to randomly send the user to the same page more than the other"?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I am aware it would alternate with a counter, which could be fine. Really any solution that guarantees a 50/50 distribution would be good for me.

Comment: @Ouroborus I am expecting to use this webapp to have ~100 people use it, and would like for it to send 50 to one page and 50 to the other. If I use the code in my question, it could randomly send more people to one page than the other, which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Well you could maintain a state variable and increment it on button click and check if its even or odd, should be fairly trivial

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava do you know if having a counter in the state keep the counter updated for any future user?

Comment: @anInputName That's a separate question but it looks like [Spectric read your mind](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68639412/227299). Their example shows you that you can store the information in `localStorage` so it remains across loads (for a single browser). This could be implemented in multiple ways, for example, you could save it on the server so it works on different browsers and even across multiple users if you choose to implement it that way.

Comment: @JuanMendes how to store the value does not solve the logic issue about how to decide to which page each user should be redirected.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano It is part of the solution, if you really want it 50/50 for all your users as the OP has mentioned in the question's comments.

Comment: You have to make your server track the users, randomly distribute the users, and send them to different routes. This is the only way you can do it if you really want 50/50 distribution.

Comment: @AyushGupta if the logic is "random" there is no difference if you perform it server or client-side. Neither does it matter if you track it... it will be random right?

Answer (score 4):

You can store the number of visits in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), then check whether the counter is even or odd:

```js
var visits = localStorage.getItem("clicks");
visits = visits ? +visits : 0;
localStorage.setItem("clicks", visits+1);
if(visits % 2 == 0){
  //redirect to /foo
}else{
  //redirect to /bar
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/Spectric/jo9ch0mb/

---

The same logic can be implemented if you want to evenly distribute a number of users with the use of a server.

Comment: There may not be a need for `localStorage` here, right? It looks like they're using the [History.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) API

Comment: From the OP's comment, it looks like they do want to persist data, but beyond just a browser.

Comment: This answer should be accepted because it does a very fine job in just a few lines. However, it does not guarantee 50/50 distribution. If you really want to achieve that, you will have to track the users on your server and send the users to different routes which could get sort of messy.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, your code has a 50/50 chance behavior. Exactly because we assume that `Math.random()` returns a true "random" number. 50/50 chance is very different from an 'alternating' logic. Chance statistically refers to a large number of tests. In other words, if you click 1000 times your button, most likely you'll be redirected 500 times to one page and 500 to the other. Just like when you throw a coin, you have 50/50 chance to get one result, but that does not exclude the possibility to get the same result 10 times or more in a row.

So, if you want to keep the 50/50 chance logic, your code is good. If you want to implement an alternating logic with a counter, you can do it as follows (not a valid solution after reading comments, see details below):

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button');

(() => {
  let state = 1;

  const handler = () => {
    state *= -1;
    
    if (state === 1) {
      alert('Case B');
    } else {
      alert('Case A');
    }
  };

  button.addEventListener('click', handler);
})();
```

```html
<button id='button' type='button'>Click Me</button>
```

**EDIT**

**Probabilistic Vs. Deterministic Approach**

The only way to solve your problem (as better described in the question comments) in a deterministic way, is to decide server-side which users will be directed to each page (making sure that there are always the same number of users assigned to each page, for example, like assigning pages alternatively to each new user). Then it doesn't matter if you pass this info each time to each user or if the user stores the value somehow on the client-side (consider that there could be more than one user per each client). This would guarantee an equal distribution at a "database" level. I mean, who says that it can't happen that at a certain moment all the users that you assigned to one page get online? And the others don't? Things can get complicate quickly and the only way to solve this is to have a dynamic server-side redirecting logic (AKA Load Balancers).

If you want to go the probabilistic way (and it is not that crazy as it seems), your code is ok and there is no need for server-side logic (server randomness is not much better than client randomness) or to store the result of the selection. Actually, it is even better if you run the random logic more times, thus statistically achieving a more homogeneous result.

I would follow the second way if there are no other strict technical bounds that require a more rigorous approach.

Just a final observation. Statistically speaking, 50/50 probability can be mathematically guaranteed. Having the exact same number of users assigned to each page can not (when we talk about 50/50 chance).

Comment: That's very true, the odd/even approach is a more strict interpretation but this could be used if the intent is that it does work 50/50 for all users ever without needing to persist anything. Whereas the existing answers only alternate for the current page/load/browser.

Comment: @JuanMendes As I commented above, I think that OP needs more than my answer, but more than yours too. I will extend my answer to make my point clearer.